# Помогите с ошибкой я не понимаю что за ошибка

Tags: python

```
a = input("Доброго дня що ви хочете зробити? 1 - прочитати файл, 2 - записати файл, 3 - дозаписати файл ")

if a == "1":
    with open('файл.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
    print(data)

if a == "2":
    with open('файл.txt', 'r') as file:
    while True:
        data = file.readline()
        if data == '':
            break

if a == "3":
    with open('text.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write('Я вас поздравляю')
```

Comment: Так а ошибка то какая?

Comment: Отступы + для варианта 2 видимо надо 'w' и f.write

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поставить отступы для строчек после with. Должно стать лучше